# How can I change the derivative symbol ' in output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, options, display

The derivative symbol in "output" is always like this `f'(x)` but I want something like `D[f[x],x]` or `df(x)/dx`.

I tried `TraditionalForm` but it didn't work in "output".

Many Thanks!

Got it! `Format[]` function is very useful!

Comment: I do not understand, If the input is `D[f[x],x]` what do you mean by you want the output to be  `D[f[x],x]`? You mean you want it to remain unevaluated? You can do `HoldForm[D[f[x],x]]` in this case. Or `TraditionalForm@HoldForm[D[f[x], x]]` which will display as you wanted. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfDFd.png)

Comment: The full form of `f'[x]` is `Derivative[1][f][x]`. You could try assigning format values; e.g. something like `Format[Derivative[1][f_][arg_]] := Row[{"[", HoldForm[D[f[x], x]], Subscript["]", x = arg]}]`